# Как управлять легендой в Seaborn

Tags: matplotlib, python-3.6, seaborn

У меня есть следующий код:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = sns.countplot(y = mean_check_city_label['label'], 
                  data = mean_check_city_label)

labels = [f"Кластер_{x}" for x in mean_check_city_label["label"].unique()]


h, l = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(h, labels, title="Метка кластера")

plt.show()
```

И в легенде отражается только само название легенды "Метка кластера", но самих обозначений из гистограммы нет
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ax = sns.countplot(y = mean_check_city_label['label'], 
                  data = mean_check_city_label, order=['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd'])

Comment: Это, к сожалению, не работает, я уже пробовала сортировать